# How to stay up-to-date regarding transport affected by recent turmoil in Thailand

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, thailand, event-based-effects

I am going to Koh Chang via Bangkok in a few weeks. I have arranged a stopover near the Ekamai bus station in Bangkok for the first night but I realize that problems of various kinds may arise from the ongoing conflict in the country. One option may be to continue directly by air. This would only require the airport to function.  Another would be to avoid Bangkok center and go some way southwest and find another stopover (a more obvious alternative since getting a ticket in the last minute may not be realistic).

Obviously the value of these choices depends on the latest news, and my question is: what do you think is the best source for this kind of information?

Comment: Getting a flight to Koh Chang would not be too dificult, the nearest arirport is Trat and there is a flight 3 times a day.  I've never seen the flight full. http://www.bangkokair.com/pages/view/trat-airport

Answer (score 4):

The [Bangkok Post](http://www.bangkokpost.com/) newspaper has up-to-date information regarding the protests. On top of that, bigger events such as an airport blockade as it happened some time ago should make international news and will also be found on the daily updates on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Thai_political_crisis).

If a specific bus station is in the vicinity of the protests can also be found out online, be it directly on [Google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=210550963008557722983.0004ea041241da07d86cb&msa=0), at the [BBC website](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/asia-pacific/8686921.stm), and [various others](https://www.google.mv/search?q=bangkok%20protests%20map&client=firefox-a&hs=Wty&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=YTrAUtjEDuHPiAe0m4DoDA&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=1600&bih=743&dpr=1).

Answer (score 2):

*Generally* the  Thai protests happen downtown, around Democracy Monument and Siam Square, you should be ok in the Ekamai area.   If you need to get some rest before going to Kho Chang there are some decent cheap guest houses around the airport at Bang Phli.  The guest house should be able to arrange a mini-bus or tell you how to get a public bus from there, since the airport is east of Ekamai.